# ¿Cómo hacer que no actualice todo un array en Firebase? Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Tengo un textarea para ingresar texto y lo almacena en un objeto, ese objeto se almacena en un array y ese array se mande a firebase, para que cuando ingrese mas información se vayan agregando los objetos nuevos. El problema es que al momento de querer agregar mas objetos a ese array, me actualiza todos los objetos de ese array con la información nueva.

html

```
    <textarea  [(ngModel)]="nghistorial" name="nghistorial" class="form-control"   >
    </textarea>
    <button (click)='SaveForm()'>Post!</button>
```

ts

```
SaveForm(){
  let historial=[];
let x=0
while(x<=this.x){


  let objeto =   {
    historial:this.nghistorial,
  
    }
    historial.push(objeto);
    this.dbData.saveHistorial(historial);
    x++
  
  
  }
this.nghistorial=''
  this.x++

 }
```

data service

```
saveHistorial(historial: Historial[]):void{
  let id=this.idCR-1
  this.afs.doc('LEADS/'+id).update({historial});// Tambien lo intente con "set" pero es lo mismo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar [arrayUnion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

```
saveHistorial(historial: Historial[]):void{
  let id=this.idCR-1
  this.afs.doc('LEADS/'+id).update({
    historial: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(historial)
  });
}
```